Bootstrap 5 Carousel will not autoplay after page load
This standard Bootstrap 5 carousel code...
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item active">
<img src="1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<img src="2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
</div>
</div>
</div>

...auto plays when it is in the html file when the page is loading.
When, however, the same code is added to the DOM after page load with:
$('#previous-div').after(carouselHTML);

...the carousel does not autoplay.
What steps do I need to take to have the carousel auto play, when the carousel is added to the DOM after page load?

I’m not sure, but I don’t think Bootstrap monitors the DOM for additions, so you may need to create a carousel instance with the carousel constructor after you’ve added it.

As per docs, Carousel components with data-bs attribute are initialized automatically on page load, so adding them later won't work.
So, you can instantiate it manually with JavaScript.
You seem to be using jQuery, so BS components are automatically available, so you can instantiate carousel by passing cycle to .carousel method:
 $('#previous-div').after($(carouselHTML).carousel('cycle'));

demo:


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div id="previous-div"></div>


  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      const carouselHTML = `
      <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/300x200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/300x200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  `;


      $('#previous-div').delay(2000).after($(carouselHTML).carousel('cycle'));



    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>




I finally got it to work with this code:
<script>
var myCarousel = document.querySelector('#carousel-id')
var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel, {interval:2000,wrap:false})
</script>

